# BigQuery Dataform Assert Esecution issue

Tags: google-bigquery, assertion, dataform

I've a BigQuery Dataform Project
and I've associated to the project  serviceaccount with these roles:
BigQuery Data Editor
BigQuery Data Owner
BigQuery Data Viewer
BigQuery Job User
Service Account Token Creator

But when i try to execute an "TAG" execution i got: "IAM permission denied for service account dataform@.iam.gserviceaccount.com.

Why?

I tryed " Start Execution" with a tag execution.
I expectced to have the result of the assertion.
I've checked on documentation (https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/required-access) and the rolese required are that i used

Comment: By project service account are you referring to the GCP service account or the dataform service account?

Comment: Hi @philMarius, we built a custom serviceaccount with only the role indicated by the documentation

Answer (score 0):

We finally found how to resolve the issue.
We are using as Git repository a project on GitHub, to connect to GitHub and we using a *secret key* to connect to GitHub.
to allow the custom service account to perform scheduled flows we added these roles:

- Secret Manager Secret Accessor
- Service Account Token Creator

to GCP defalut Dataform service account, see: [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/254626248#comment20).
We tryed to give these roles to our service account but in this way we got the error.
Giving the rolese to GCP defalut Dataform service account now all works fine.